# Docker+Django+SECRET_KEY: regenerate?

Tags: django, docker, settings, secret-key

Imagine you create a docker-compose.yml with Django and a bunch of code and use an environment variable to configure the SECRET_KEY in settings.py.

If you distribute that Docker image you won't share the SECRET_KEY.

**What SECRET_KEY should someone use when they deploy your Docker image?**

They can't make up their own SECRET_KEY right?

> According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#secret-key), changing the secret key will invalidate:
>
> - All sessions if you are using any other session backend than django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache, or are using the default get_session_auth_hash().
> - All messages if you are using CookieStorage or FallbackStorage.
> - All PasswordResetView tokens.
> - Any usage of cryptographic signing, unless a different key is provided.

What's the best way to 'renerate' a secret key after deploying a Docker container with a bunch of code that you created?

(I have searched and searched but feel like I'm searching for the wrong things or completely missed something :-)

Answer (score 3):

Everybody who deploys the service independently should have their own `SECRET_KEY`.  (You actively do not want the things you describe to be shared across installations: if I’ve logged into my copy of your service, I shouldn’t be able to reuse my session cookie on your copy.) A command I typically use for this is

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=60 count=1 | base64
```

which will generate an 80-character high-quality random key.

The corollary to this is that you can’t distribute encrypted data with your image.  That’s usually not a problem (it is difficult to distribute a prepopulated relational database in Docker) and if you do this by running database migration and seed jobs at first startup, they should be able to use whatever key you set when you do the installation.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is platform agnostic because it uses the original Django key generator.

```py
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key

get_random_secret_key()
```

It can be used standalone without initializing a Django project.